# How to initialize a protected class variable in C++; LNK2001

Tags: c++, oop, static

I'm trying to teach myself C++, but the error messages are less than helpful in my debugger. The short version is that I have declared a Bank_Account class with a next_account_number class variable. That variable is protected and static since I want it to be held by the class rather than its members and not directly accessible. I know that C++ will not allow me to initialize the variable in the class's declaration, so my solution was to create a public static initialize() method within the class. Despite this, I am unable to compile my code now that I have added this to my class. I'm certain this is possible, but I have no idea what keyword I'm missing. I have posted the relevant bits below.

```
/* Bank_Account.h */
class Bank_Account {
protected:
    static unsigned int next_account_number;
public:
    /**
     * Initializes the class' static variables. In the future, this will
     *   involve reading previous values from a file, but it simply initializes
     *   the next_account_number to 0 for now;
     */
    static void initialize();
}
```

```
/* Bank_Account.cpp */
#include "Bank_Account.h"

void Bank_Account::initialize() {
    next_account_number = 0;
}
```

```
/* Main.cpp */
#include "Bank_Account.h"


int main() {
    Bank_Account::initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile this results in the following:

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: static unsigned
> int Bank_Account::next_account_number"
> (?next_account_number@Bank_Account@@2IA)  LearningProject C:\...\Bank_Account.obj    1

Comment: And where is there the variable defined? You need to define it. In the class definition it is only declared.

Comment: You need `unsigned int Bank_Account::next_account_number = 0;`  in `Bank_Account.cpp` instead of the `initialize()` function. You could just remove that function.

Comment: I'll also add that static variables are initialized before entering the `main()` function, so the `initialize()` method is probably unnecessary in this case